# Laravel Email template route with parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-mail

I create a simple email function using Laravel, the user gets an email and in that email I would like to call a route which Downloads a file.

My Mailable:

```
class AppSent extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $name = '';

    public function __construct(String $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME'))
                    ->markdown('emails.download.android_app');
    }
}
```

on button click I call this function in my DownloadController which sends an email to the user:

```
return Mail::to($request->email)->queue(new AppSent($request->name));
```

This is the markdown view (email view) which the user gets:

```
@component('mail::message')
    Hi,

    Downloadlink created

    @component('mail::button', ['url' => 'https://myapp.com/download'])
    Download!

    @endcomponent    
@endcomponent
```

This is the route I Need to call to download the zip file:

```
public function download(Request $request)
{
    return response()->download(
        storage_path('/app/uploaded_apps/' . $request->name . '.zip')
    );
}
```

How can I add the Parameter in my download blade view to download a specific file with a given Name?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Parameter in the url array:

```
@component('mail::message')
    Hi,

    Downloadlink created

    @component('mail::button', ['url' => 'https://myapp.com/download', 'name' => $name])
    Download!

    @endcomponent    
@endcomponent
```

Comment: Did not work, it just Redirected me to the /download page and did not download

Comment: Can you post the generated link.

Answer (score 0):

What about to create a route like this one:
routes.php

```
Route::get('download/{name}', function($name){
   return response()->download(
        storage_path('/app/uploaded_apps/' . $name . '.zip')
    );
});
```

Youcan also put the download function into a controller...Let us call it DownloadController and then you could call it:

```
Route::get('download/{name}', 'DownloadController@download');
```

You will need to have the download function accepting $name as argument instead of Request request.

Then in the mail blade:

```
 @component('mail::button', ['url' => 'https://myapp.com/download/'.$name])
    Download!
@endcomponent
```

Hope this could help you.